# Evaluating $H_G$ when $H\leq G$ is subgroup of all diagonal invertible matrices.

Tags: group-theory

I am working on some basic context in Group Theory. I face to the following problem:

> Let $G=GL(2,\Bbb Q)$ and $H\leq G$ be the subgroup of all diagonal invertible matrices. Find $$H_G=\cap_{g\in G}g^{-1}Hg$$

What I have done is to assume $H=\Big\{ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & 0 \\
0 & b \\\end{array} \right)\mid ab \neq 0, a,b\in \Bbb Q\Big\}$ and take an arbitrary element $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x & y \\
z & t \\
\end{array} \right) \in G$, and find the natural form of elements in $H_G$:

[image]

But, clearly, I am on a wrong track. Please note me if you know applicable way for doing the core of $H$ in $G$. Thanks!

Comment: Nice question...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have for say $g = id$ that $gHg^{-1} = H$ so the question reduces to: which diagonal invertible matrices $\begin{pmatrix} c \\ & d \end{pmatrix}$ can be found in $gHg^{-1}$ for all $g$.

I claim that these are precisely $\lambda Id$, for $\lambda \in \mathbb{Q} - 0$.

To see this is necessary, if $x,y,z,t$ are all nonzero, for the resulting matrix $g^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} a \\ & b \end{pmatrix} g$ which you just computed to be diagonal, we need that $a = b =: \lambda$, which gives just those of the form $$\begin{pmatrix} \lambda \\ & \lambda \end{pmatrix}$$

To see this is sufficient, such a matrix $\lambda Id$ commutes with any other $g$, hence $g \lambda Id g^{-1} = \lambda Id$.

Comment: Oh, thanks....I can see where I was confused in. Yes yes I see my defect. Thanks.

Comment: So the core of $H$ will be $(\Bbb Q^*,.)$. Thanks

Comment: No worries! It was a fun problem :)